# Using ReadDirectoryChangesW asynchronously in a loop

Tags: c++, winapi, asynchronous, readdirectorychangesw

## INTRODUCTION:

I am trying to use [ReadDirectoryChangesW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465(v=vs.85).aspx)  asynchronously in a loop.

Below snippet illustrates what I am trying to achieve:

```
DWORD example()
{
    DWORD error = 0;

    OVERLAPPED ovl = { 0 };
    ovl.hEvent = ::CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

    if (NULL == ovl.hEvent) return ::GetLastError();

    char buffer[1024];

    while(1)
    {
        process_list_of_existing_files();

        error = ::ReadDirectoryChangesW(
            m_hDirectory, // I have added FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED in CreateFile
            buffer, sizeof(buffer), FALSE,
            FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME,
            NULL, &ovl, NULL);

        // we have new files, append them to the list
        if(error) append_new_files_to_the_list(buffer);
        // just continue with the loop
        else if(::GetLastError() == ERROR_IO_PENDING) continue;
        // RDCW error, this is critical -> exit
        else return ::GetLastError(); 
    }
}
```

## PROBLEM:

I do not know how to handle the case when `ReadDirectoryChangesW` returns `FALSE` with `GetLastError()` code being `ERROR_IO_PENDING`.

In that case I should just continue with the loop and keep looping until `ReadDirectoryChangesW` returns `buffer` I can process.

## MY EFFORTS TO SOLVE THIS:

I have tried using `WaitForSingleObject(ovl.hEvent, 1000)` but it crashes with error `1450 ERROR_NO_SYSTEM_RESOURCES`. Below is the MVCE that reproduces this behavior:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

DWORD processDirectoryChanges(const char *buffer)
{
    DWORD offset = 0;
    char fileName[MAX_PATH] = "";
    FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION *fni = NULL;

    do
    {
        fni = (FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION*)(&buffer[offset]);
        // since we do not use UNICODE, 
        // we must convert fni->FileName from UNICODE to multibyte
        int ret = ::WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, fni->FileName,
            fni->FileNameLength / sizeof(WCHAR),
            fileName, sizeof(fileName), NULL, NULL);

        switch (fni->Action)
        {
        case FILE_ACTION_ADDED:     
        {
            std::cout << fileName << std::endl;
        }
        break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        ::memset(fileName, '\0', sizeof(fileName));
        offset += fni->NextEntryOffset;

    } while (fni->NextEntryOffset != 0);

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE hDir = ::CreateFile("C:\\Users\\nenad.smiljkovic\\Desktop\\test", 
        FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
        NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 
        FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);

    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hDir) return ::GetLastError();

    OVERLAPPED ovl = { 0 };
    ovl.hEvent = ::CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

    if (NULL == ovl.hEvent) return ::GetLastError();

    DWORD error = 0, br;
    char buffer[1024];

    while (1)
    {
        error = ::ReadDirectoryChangesW(hDir,
            buffer, sizeof(buffer), FALSE,
            FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME,
            NULL, &ovl, NULL);

        if (0 == error)
        {
            error = ::GetLastError();

            if (ERROR_IO_PENDING != error)
            {
                ::CloseHandle(ovl.hEvent);
                ::CloseHandle(hDir);
                return error;
            }
        }

        error = ::WaitForSingleObject(ovl.hEvent, 0);

        switch (error)
        {
        case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
            break;
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
        {
            error = processDirectoryChanges(buffer);

            if (error > 0)
            {
                ::CloseHandle(ovl.hEvent);
                ::CloseHandle(hDir);
                return error;
            }

            if (0 == ::ResetEvent(ovl.hEvent))
            {
                error = ::GetLastError();
                ::CloseHandle(ovl.hEvent);
                ::CloseHandle(hDir);
                return error;
            }
        }
        break;
        default:
            error = ::GetLastError();
            ::CloseHandle(ovl.hEvent);
            ::CloseHandle(hDir);
            return error;
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Reading through the documentation, it seems that I need [GetOverlappedResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683209(v=vs.85).aspx) with last parameter set to `FALSE` but I do not know how to use this API properly.

## QUESTION:

Since the MVCE illustrates very well what I am trying to do (print the names of the newly added files), can you show me what must be fixed in the `while` loop in order for it to work?

*Again, the point is to use `ReadDirectoryChangesW` asynchronously, in a loop, as shown in the snippet from the INTRODUCTION.*

Comment: That code does not make much sense.  It blows up because you use a 0 timeout instead of INFINITE so you are not actually waiting and call ReadDirectoryChangesW at a very high rate.  Only ever use OVERLAPPED if you have something else to do.  So you can use WaitForMultipleObjects().  As posted you should not use it.

Comment: @HansPassant: If RDCW does not return buffer I can use, I would like to `continue` the loop, executing other code ( `foo()` from the top ) until I get filled buffer. That was the point I waited 0 seconds. If nothing is available then the loop continues, otherwise I process the buffer content. I apologize for confusion, I am not native English speaker, so I understand if my intention is not clear at first read.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff if RDCW returns an IO Pending error, simply do not call RDCW again until the overlapped event has been signaled first. You can keep looping and doing other things in the meantime. In the code shown, call RDCW one time before entering the loop, and then call it again in the `WAIT_OBJECT_0` handler.

Comment: One of your mistakes is comparing the return value to `ERROR_IO_PENDING`.  That's not a return value of `ReadDirectoryChangesW`, it's a `GetLastError()` value.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I do not understand, I am comparing `ERROR_IO_PENDING` against `GetLastError()` call, in the MVCE.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff: I'm talking about your first code block, `example()`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Missed that one because it was supposed to be a pseudo-code. I will fix it in a second. Thank you.

Comment: If you're running it in a tight loop like that why do you want to use async anyway? Just use a blocking call.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: based on the discussion following the earlier answer, I believe he wants to perform background tasks during the loop, even though the MCVE doesn't show this.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: I need the loop to work continuously. With blocking call it will be blocked until a change in the directory occurs.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff - use callbacks for handle directory change events and work "continuosly" :)

Comment: or use wait on your event `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx` if you have gui thread and want not block it. however use APC with `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx` will be better - more power, scalable and clean code compare async event model

Comment: look like OP want do some task_1 based on directory change event and some another task_2 based on timer,or user request, or remote request, etc (does not matter). and he don't know how combine it. he think that this is possible only if use loop in single function. encapsulate data in `struct` and call different methods on different events (with possible synchronizations like critical_section use) look like too complex and unacceptable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic structure of your program looks more or less OK, you're just using the asynchronous I/O calls incorrectly.  Whenever there are no new files, the wait on the event handle times out immediately, which is fine, but you then issue a brand new I/O request, which isn't.

That's why you're running out of system resources; you're issuing I/O requests full tilt without waiting for any of them to complete.  You should only issue a new request *after the existing request has completed.*

(Also, you should be calling GetOverlappedResult to check whether the I/O was successful or not.)

So your loop should look more like this:

```
    ::ReadDirectoryChangesW(hDir,
        buffer, sizeof(buffer), FALSE,
        FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME,
        NULL, &ovl, NULL);

    while (1)
    {
        DWORD dw;
        DWORD result = ::WaitForSingleObject(ovl.hEvent, 0);

        switch (result)
        {
        case WAIT_TIMEOUT:

            processBackgroundTasks();

            break;

        case WAIT_OBJECT_0:

            ::GetOverlappedResult(hDir, &ovl, &dw, FALSE);

            processDirectoryChanges(buffer);

            ::ResetEvent(ovl.hEvent);

            ::ReadDirectoryChangesW(hDir,
                buffer, sizeof(buffer), FALSE,
                FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME,
                NULL, &ovl, NULL);

            break;
        }
    }
```

Notes:

- The error handling has been elided for simplicity; I have not done any testing or checked your code for any other problems.
- If there might not be any background tasks to perform, you should test for that case and set the timeout to INFINITE rather than 0 when it occurs, otherwise you will be spinning.
- I wanted to only show the minimal changes necessary to make it work, but calling WaitForSingleObject followed by GetOverlappedResult is redundant; a single call to GetOverlappedResult can both check whether the I/O is complete and retrieve the results if it is.

---

As requested, the modified version using only GetOverlappedResult and with minimal error checking.  I've also added an example of how you might deal with the case where you've run out of work to do; if whatever processing you're doing on the files really does run forever, you don't need that bit.

```
    ::ResetEvent(ovl.hEvent);

    if (!::ReadDirectoryChangesW(hDir,
        buffer, sizeof(buffer), FALSE,
        FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME,
        NULL, &ovl, NULL))
    {
       error = GetLastError();
       if (error != ERROR_IO_PENDING) fail();
    }

    while (1)
    {
        BOOL wait;

        result = process_list_of_existing_files();

        if (result == MORE_WORK_PENDING)
        {
           wait = FALSE;
        } 
        else if (result == NO_MORE_WORK_PENDING)
        {
           wait = TRUE;
        } 

        if (!::GetOverlappedResult(hDir, &ovl, &dw, wait))
        {
           error = GetLastError();
           if (error == ERROR_IO_INCOMPLETE) continue;
           fail();
        }

        processDirectoryChanges(buffer);

        ::ResetEvent(ovl.hEvent);

        if (!::ReadDirectoryChangesW(hDir,
            buffer, sizeof(buffer), FALSE,
            FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME,
            NULL, &ovl, NULL))
        {
           error = GetLastError();
           if (error != ERROR_IO_PENDING) fail();
        } 
    }
```

Comment: call ReadDirectoryChangesW asynchronously and then WaitForSingleObject - almost kill asynchronous behaviour. only one advantage of this kind of loop - `processBackgroundTasks();` except this - we can call ReadDirectoryChangesW synchronously with same effect. but look like main problem of OP - he not understand how asynchronous work at all, how bind context to operation and then use in callbacks..

Comment: Thank you for answering. Regarding your 2nd observation, the goal I am aiming to achieve is shown in code snippet in INTRODUCTION. Regarding your 3rd observation, can you edit your answer to show how to properly use `GetOverlappedResult`? I would really like to do this right. Regarding error checking, I need to handle them, so if you could atleast handle ERROR_IO_PENDING that should be enough.Thanks again for answering.

Comment: Without a description of what `process_list_of_existing_files();` actually does, that snippet isn't really very useful.  If there will *always* be work to do, you needn't worry about spinning, it's just that this seems unlikely - surely if the user stops adding new files, you'll *eventually* finish whatever it is you are doing on the existing ones?

Comment: *surely if the user stops adding new files, you'll eventually finish whatever it is you are doing on the existing ones?* As long as the app is working `process_list_of_existing_files();` will be called. Users should quit the app by pressing Ctrl + C, otherwise it will run forever. I had come up with the solution similar to yours (from the edit) thanks to your original answer + hints from user *Remy Lebeau*. There is no need to update my OP with that code, I will simply accept your answer. I will upvote your answer too. Thanks.

Comment: What does `dw` variable stand for in this answer?

Comment: @TomášZato, oh, that's an old Windows convention - `dw` for `DWORD`.  I've added a declaration to the code.  In this code it receives the number of bytes transferred into the buffer.  Because of the structure of the data returned by ReadDirectoryChangesW we don't actually need to know the number of bytes, but we still need a variable to put it in.

Answer (score 3):

**Variant of indirect using IOCP**

1. Create a class/struct inherited (containing) `OVERLAPPED` (or
   `IO_STATUS_BLOCK`), a reference counter, directory handle and data which
   you need
2. Call [`BindIoCompletionCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363484(v=vs.85).aspx) (`RtlSetIoCompletionCallback`) for
   directory handle, for setup your callback
3. Have a `DoRead()` routine, which we'll call first-time from the main thread, and then from the callback
4. In `DoRead()`, before every call to `ReadDirectoryChangesW` call
   `AddRef();` because we pass reference (across `OVERLAPPED`) to our
   struct to kernel
5. Main (say GUI thread) can continue to do own task after the initial call
   to `DoRead()`, unlike the APC variant, we do not need to wait in alertable state
6. In the callback, we got a pointer to our struct from inherited (containing)
   `OVERLAPPED`. Do any tasks (`processDirectoryChanges`), if need
   continue spy - call `DoRead()` and finally call `Release()`
7. If `ReadDirectoryChangesW` from `DoRead()` fails (as result will be no callback) - we need direct call callback
   with error code
8. For stopping we can simply close the directory handle - as a result, we got
   `STATUS_NOTIFY_CLEANUP` in callback

==================================

```
//#define _USE_NT_VERSION_

class SPYDATA : 
#ifdef _USE_NT_VERSION_
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK
#else
    OVERLAPPED 
#endif
{
    HANDLE _hFile;
    LONG _dwRef;
    union {
        FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION _fni;
        UCHAR _buf[PAGE_SIZE];
    };

    void DumpDirectoryChanges()
    {
        union {
            PVOID buf;
            PBYTE pb;
            PFILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION pfni;
        };

        buf = _buf;

        for (;;)
        {
            DbgPrint("%x <%.*S>\n", pfni->Action, pfni->FileNameLength >> 1, pfni->FileName);

            ULONG NextEntryOffset = pfni->NextEntryOffset;

            if (!NextEntryOffset)
            {
                break;
            }

            pb += NextEntryOffset;
        }
    }

#ifdef _USE_NT_VERSION_
    static VOID WINAPI _OvCompRoutine(
        _In_    NTSTATUS dwErrorCode,
        _In_    ULONG_PTR dwNumberOfBytesTransfered,
        _Inout_ PIO_STATUS_BLOCK Iosb
        )
    {
        static_cast<SPYDATA*>(Iosb)->OvCompRoutine(dwErrorCode, (ULONG)dwNumberOfBytesTransfered);
    }
#else
    static VOID WINAPI _OvCompRoutine(
        _In_    DWORD dwErrorCode, // really this is NTSTATUS
        _In_    DWORD dwNumberOfBytesTransfered,
        _Inout_ LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
        )
    {
        static_cast<SPYDATA*>(lpOverlapped)->OvCompRoutine(dwErrorCode, dwNumberOfBytesTransfered);
    }
#endif

    VOID OvCompRoutine(NTSTATUS status, DWORD dwNumberOfBytesTransfered)
    {
        DbgPrint("[%x,%x]\n", status, dwNumberOfBytesTransfered);

        if (0 <= status) 
        {
            if (status != STATUS_NOTIFY_CLEANUP)
            {
                if (dwNumberOfBytesTransfered) DumpDirectoryChanges();
                process_list_of_existing_files();// so hard do this here ?!?
                DoRead();
            }
            else
            {
                DbgPrint("\n---- NOTIFY_CLEANUP -----\n");
            }
        }

        Release();
        MyReleaseRundownProtection();
    }

    ~SPYDATA()
    {
        Cancel();
    }

public:

    void DoRead()
    {
        if (MyAcquireRundownProtection())
        {
            AddRef();
#ifdef _USE_NT_VERSION_
            NTSTATUS status = ZwNotifyChangeDirectoryFile(_hFile, 0, 0, this, this, &_fni, sizeof(_buf), FILE_NOTIFY_VALID_MASK, TRUE);
            if (NT_ERROR(status))
            {
                OvCompRoutine(status, 0);
            }
#else
            if (!ReadDirectoryChangesW(_hFile, _buf, sizeof(_buf), TRUE, FILE_NOTIFY_VALID_MASK, (PDWORD)&InternalHigh, this, 0))
            {
                OvCompRoutine(RtlGetLastNtStatus(), 0);
            }
#endif
        }
    }

    SPYDATA()
    {
        _hFile = 0;// ! not INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE because use ntapi for open file
        _dwRef = 1;
#ifndef _USE_NT_VERSION_
        RtlZeroMemory(static_cast<OVERLAPPED*>(this), sizeof(OVERLAPPED));
#endif
    }

    void AddRef()
    {
        InterlockedIncrement(&_dwRef);
    }

    void Release()
    {
        if (!InterlockedDecrement(&_dwRef))
        {
            delete this;
        }
    }

    BOOL Create(POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES poa)
    {
        IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;
        NTSTATUS status = ZwOpenFile(&_hFile, FILE_GENERIC_READ, poa, &iosb, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE);
        if (0 <= status)
        {
            return
#ifdef _USE_NT_VERSION_
                0 <= RtlSetIoCompletionCallback(_hFile, _OvCompRoutine, 0);
#else
                BindIoCompletionCallback(_hFile, _OvCompRoutine, 0);
#endif
        }
        return FALSE;
    }

    void Cancel()
    {
        if (HANDLE hFile = InterlockedExchangePointer(&_hFile, 0))
        {
            NtClose(hFile);
        }
    }
};

void DemoF()
{
    if (MyInitializeRundownProtection())
    {
        STATIC_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES(oa, "<SOME_DIRECTORY>");

        if (SPYDATA* p = new SPYDATA)
        {
            if (p->Create(&oa))
            {
                p->DoRead();
            }

            //++ GUI thread run
            MessageBoxW(0, L"wait close program...", L"", MB_OK);
            //-- GUI thread end

            p->Cancel();

            p->Release();
        }

        MyWaitForRundownProtectionRelease();
    }
}
```

Comment: I fail to see how IOCP/ACP fits in my task. If you look at the code snippet from INTRODUCTION, the whole confusion revolves around this: I need to know *immediately after I process the list of existing files* if new files were added to the directory. I fail to understand how will IOCP/ACP tell me *in that moment* if there are new files in the directory. Can you please help me understand? Thank you

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff - so do your task(process the list of existing files ) - in callback. in what problem ?

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff - again and again - you completely not understand asynchronous programming at all and this case as well. only this not fit to your task

Comment: The list processing must work *always* not just when callback is triggered. If I understand you well, list processing will run only when the callback is invoked (when new files are added). The only way I see this to work, is to duplicate the code from `while` loop in callback as well.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff - "The list processing must work always " - what you mean under this ? if you need do some task, independent from directory change events - do this direct, in what problem ?? in synchronization ?

Comment: *in what problem ?? in synchronization ?* Yes, synchronization. Look at the code snippet from introduction. First I go through list of existing files and do something (let us say I just read something from them). Once I finish, and that is the point -> once I finish with the existing ones, I must check *in that moment* if new files are added to the directory (this is where IOCP/ACP/whatever comes into play). If new files are added, add them to the list. The list gets processed in next iteration.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff - your problem only in programming skills and knowledge. here i cannot help you if you not understand at all

Comment: +1 for the thread pool trick using BindIoCompletionCallback. Sounds obvious when you see it but no one mentions it elsewhere.

Comment: @SimonMourier - strange, i always think that this is obvious. also possible here use new pool api `CreateThreadpoolIo` call on file handle. `StartThreadpoolIo` before every io begin and `CancelThreadpoolIo` if io request synchronous fail. and `CloseThreadpoolIo` when you close handle. but i prefer use old `BindIoCompletionCallback`

Comment: @SimonMourier - also if you want use [`BindIoCompletionCallback`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-bindiocompletioncallback) - note *The value returned is an NTSTATUS error code. To retrieve the corresponding system error code, use the `RtlNtStatusToDosError` function* - this is mitake in documentation. if api fail - it return usual win32 code, but in callback - [`LpoverlappedCompletionRoutine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/nc-minwinbase-lpoverlapped_completion_routine) - `DWORD dwErrorCode` is really `NTSTATUS`.

Comment: so *use the `RtlNtStatusToDosError` function`* related to parametr of callback, not to returned error code

Comment: Thanks. I don't seem to get many errors :-), but I'll do that.

Comment: @SimonMourier - this even not about error - first parameter of LPOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE callback function - despite declared as `DWORD dwErrorCode` - really - `NTSTATUS status` - not translated to win32 code. you how minimum will get `STATUS_NOTIFY_CLEANUP` when close file handle or `STATUS_CANCELLED` if call `CancelIoEx` (but not `ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED`). and sometime you can get `STATUS_NOTIFY_ENUM_DIR`. if you `CreateThreadpoolIo` it translate ntstatus to win32 error before callback - and you got already win32 errors (say `ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED` if you call `CancelIoEx`)

Comment: but here you **lost** `STATUS_NOTIFY_CLEANUP` and `STATUS_NOTIFY_ENUM_DIR` (it incorrect translated to noerror). but initial status anyway will be inside overlaped